# How do you conditionally route to an action if the request originates from an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

Using APS.NET routing, how do you conditionally route to separate actions based on whether or not the request originated as an AJAX call?

For instance on a controller I may have two actions:

```
public ActionResult List() { return View(); }
```

and

```
public ActionResult ListJSON() { return Content(...); }
```

I'd like both actions to have the same URL, but ListJSON() should get called if the request originated as an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can easily define your own route constraints by implementing `IRouteConstraint`.

Something like this:

```
public class AjaxRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
        return httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Then simply use this constraint on a route. The trick is that the route with this constraint must come before the route without the constraint, otherwise the ajax route will never be called (the not-ajax route will always match).

There may be some consequences to doing this when it comes to URL generation. But I have not significantly tested those.

Answer (score 2):

Why using 2 separate actions when the code is the same? It's the view result that differs.

How about:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    var model = ...
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    return Json(model);
}
```

Obviously if you had to do this in every controller action this would quickly become a complete nightmare.

So you could externalize this logic into a custom action filter:

```
[MyFilter]
public ActionResult List()
{
    var model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

where you could define the `MyFilterAttribute` like so:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
     {
         if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())   
         {
             var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
             if (result != null)
             {
                 filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                 {
                     Data = result.Model,
                     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                 };
             }
         }
     }
}
```

You could also register this action filter as a global action filter to avoid the need of putting it on each controller and action that requires it.

---

UPDATE:

As explained in the comments section it seems that the OP requires 2 different actions. For this purpose you could use a custom route:

```
public class MyRoute : Route
{
    public MyRoute(string url, object defaults) :
        base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            rd.Values["action"] = rd.GetRequiredString("action") + "json";
        }

        return rd;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(
        "Default",
        new MyRoute(
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The code is likely to NOT be the same. The queries executed, and data required are likely to differ significantly. From a testability perspective, it is a lot cleaner to have two methods, but route between them based on the request.

Comment: that's a clever idea. However since you're manipulating the "action" value, I wonder how it would affect generation of outbound URLs.